# iOS set cell height to height of UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a TableView, in the first cell i display HTML content in a WebView.

I want this cell to have the height of the content in the WebView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cell = articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("articleContentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArticleContentTableViewCell
        cell.articleContentWebView.loadHTMLString(newsItem.entry.content, baseURL: nil)
        return cell
    }

...

}
```

How do i calculate this? Can i even calculate it in CellForRowAtIndexPath as the cell is not rendered yet? I could get the scrollView height in the webview, but it's not getting me the height.

Comment: Do you have the UIWebView height?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView into a UITableViewCell with dynamic size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709899/uiwebview-into-a-uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-size)

Comment: you can calculate in cell method awakefromnib!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) loadString (NSString *)Str{
[theWebView loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:nil];}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate methods

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector
:@selector(updateCellHeight:currentSection:)]) {

    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size.height += 10.0f; 
    webView.frame = frame;
    webView.delegate = nil;

 [self.delegate updateCellHeight:webView.scrollView.contentSize.height currentSection:webView.tag];
}
}

#pragma mark - RichTextCellDelegate

- (void) updateCellHeight:(CGFloat)richTextHeight currentSection:(NSInteger)Section
{

    if (![sectionArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:Section]]){
        [sectionArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:Section]];
        NSLog(@"CurrentHeight%f",richTextHeight);
        richTextCellHeight = richTextHeight;
        savedIndexPath = Section;
        //[theTableView reloadData]; // No Need to load Whole Table

       NSIndexSet *indexes = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:Section];
        [theTableView reloadSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

 }
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c". Please edit your answer and use Swift code.